# Step Failure not reported by Composed Task Runner or reflected in Spring Cloud Dataflow Tables

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently we are using Spring Cloud Dataflow to run a sequence of apps we have created based on a definition. Each of the apps we have made are spring batch jobs, with individual steps. The current issue we are having is that when one of these steps inside the app's batch job fails, it is reflected as expected in the step_execution, job_execution, and task_execution tables in the scdf database. However, we are not able to rerun any scdf job that has failed in an app from the top scdf level because it seems the row entry in the step_execution table for SCDF's step related to the overall app never propagates to FAILED in the status column, instead always being COMPLETED no matter what happens. Below I have included a picture which gets across what I am saying. test-simple8-test-app is the app we have created, while check-step, sleep-step, and should-error-step are steps inside the job for that app. You can see in the should-error-step that it has FAILED for both ExitCode and Status, while the entry for the app itself has COMPLETED for status and FAILED for ExitCode.

[Relevant Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bqim.png)

We have tried altering what we report in the task_execution table since we saw CTR is looking for certain fields there, but it still seems it does not affect the Status column in step_executions. If we manually change the entry in the db to FAILED for that value, it proceeds as we would expect and as is normal for spring batch, in that it resumes the job from that app and re executes it.

Is there a good way to relieve this problem, or is it a problem with the way we are approaching it?

Edit: [Added Flow Diagram for better clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMpCU.png)

Comment: There are so many states listed above and it is hard to follow. Would it be possible to share a simplified project that mimick's this problem? It will be easy to investigate then.

Comment: It would be hard to give a full simplified project for a few reasons, so I've added a diagram I hope better explains what I am getting at.